# Como retornar varias linhas com array de byte do sql Server

Tags: c#, array, sql-server, winforms

Preciso realizar uma consulta, em uma tabela, onde os dados são do tipo `varbinary(max)`, então criei o metodo abaixo:

```
public List<byte[]> preenche_fotos(string nCrm)
    {
        consql.bd_string();
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(consql.sqlconn);

        List<byte[]> list_foto = new List<byte[]>();

        try
        {
            consql._sql = @"SELECT bfoto
                            FROM crm_fotos
                            WHERE ncrm = @nCrm";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(consql._sql, sqlconn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@nCrm", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = nCrm;

            sqlconn.Open();

            SqlDataReader leitor = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (leitor.Read())
            {
                list_foto.Add(???????);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlconn.Close();
        }

        return list_foto;
    } 
}
```

Então, com o metodo `Read` do `DataReader`, vou lendo linha a linha da consulta, porem como faço para adicionar o valor ao `list_foto`?

Comment: Deu certo a solução?

Comment: Perfeito amigo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para passar os valores seria um `cast` para o *`array de bytes`* (`byte[]`) da seguinte forma:

```
while (leitor.Read())
{
    list_foto.Add((byte[])leitor['bfoto']);
}
```

onde `leitor['bfoto']` ***bfoto*** é nome do campo da tabela.

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Reading binary from table column into byte[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332960/reading-binary-from-table-column-into-byte-array)
- [How to Store and Read Byte Array in SQL Server Database using C# .Net](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/05/How-to-Store-and-Read-Byte-Array-in-SQL-Server-using-CSharp.html)
- [Read and Write BLOB Data to SQL Server database using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Write-BLOB-Data-to-SQL-Server-database-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)