# Upload imagem para picturebox e gravar na base de dados

Tags: c#

Estou agora na parte dos filmes do video club, onde tenho estes campos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E queria fazer o upload da imagem para a pictura box (já esta a funcionar) e ao fazer novo esta ficasse gravada na base da dados (criei um campo capa do tipo image).É possível?

Eu tentei fazer tal como faço para as txtboxs:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classimdb", txtClassIMDB.Text);
```

Colocando em vez do `txtClassIMDB.text' tentei`picturebox1.image`. Mas como é óbvio não funciona.

Comment: Daniel, nao é necessario informar linguagem no titulo, a tag já identifica a linguagem na sua pergunta.

Comment: OK.
Por acaso não me sabe ajudar com este problema?

Comment: @DanielSousa, acredito que a resposta do Thomas resolva seu problema. Mas fica como dica aqui que [nem sempre isso é uma boa solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12687/%C3%89-errado-gravar-byte-de-imagens-no-banco-de-dados).

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann muito interessante, obrigado por complementar a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Código que usei e funcionou:

```
                FileStream Stream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(Stream);
            img = binary.ReadBytes((int)Stream.Length);
            if (txtNameMovie.Text != "" && txtIDMovie.Text != "")
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Filmes(IdFilme,Titulo,Realizador,Genero,Ano,ClassifIdade,ClassfImdb,Formato,Capa) values(@id,@titulo,@realizador,@categoria,@ano,@classidade,@classimdb,@formato,@capa)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtIDMovie.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titulo", txtNameMovie.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@realizador", txtRealizador.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoria", txtCatMovies.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", txtAnoMovie.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classidade", txtClassIdade.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classimdb", txtClassIMDB.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@formato", cbFormato.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@capa", img));
                int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlCon.Close();
                disp_data();
                ClearData();
                MessageBox.Show("Filme gravado com sucesso!", "Operação Realizada com Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Para salvar uma foto em BD, um dos meios que conheço, é transformar a foto em um Array de `byte`, para isso utilizo o método abaixo:

```
          if (Pic.Image != null)
          {
               using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
               {
                    Pic.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);                                        

                    byte[] Bfoto = stream.ToArray();

                    Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Analise_CRM Cad_Foto = new Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Analise_CRM();

                    Cad_Foto.Cad_Foto_Anal_Crm(textEdit8.Text, Bfoto, Pic.Name, Pic.Properties.ZoomPercent);
                }

                 Pic.Image.Dispose();
                 Pic.Image = null;
          }
```

Agora, no banco de dados, utilize `[varbinary]` na coluna aonde ira salvar as fotos:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Crm_Fotos]
(
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Bfoto] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[item] [varchar](150) NULL,
[foto_seq] [varchar](200) NULL
(
```

Ai basta passar o parâmetro como qualquer outro dado, unica diferença é utilizando:

`cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bfoto", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = Bfoto;`

Perguntas com respostas que podem ajudar:

[Como retornar varias linhas com array de byte do sql Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203773/como-retornar-varias-linhas-com-array-de-byte-do-sql-server)

[Converter e salvar foto em BD](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/202989/converter-e-salvar-foto-em-bd)

[É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12687/%C3%89-errado-gravar-byte-de-imagens-no-banco-de-dados)

Comment: Vou tentar, obrigado!

Comment: textEdit8.Text - Esta parte é necessário ter?

Comment: Outra questao coloco esse código a seguir a este:

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (Pic.Image != null)
      {
           using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
           {
                Pic.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);                                        

                byte[] Bfoto = stream.ToArray();

                Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Analise_CRM Cad_Foto = new Classes.Cadastro.Crm.Analise_CRM();

                Cad_Foto.Cad_Foto_Anal_Crm(textEdit8.Text, Bfoto, Pic.Name, Pic.Properties.ZoomPercent);
            }

             Pic.Image.Dispose();
             Pic.Image = null;
      }
```

Essa parte vai a seguir a:

```
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Filmes(IdFilme,Titulo,Realizador,Genero,Ano,ClassifIdade,ClassfImdb,Capa) values(@id,@nome,@realizador,@categoria,@ano,@classidade,@classimdb,@capa)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtIDMovie.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtNameMovie.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@realizador", txtRealizador.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoria", txtCatMovies.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", txtAnoMovie.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classidade", txtClassIdade.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classimdb", txtClassIMDB.Text);
```