# Salvar Imagem no Banco de Dados com C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, imagem, asp.net-core

Olá!

Vi o exemplo [Upload imagem para picturebox e gravar na base de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/206359/upload-imagem-para-picturebox-e-gravar-na-base-de-dados) mas não entendi essa parte:

```
FileStream Stream = new FileStream(imgLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

O que seria esse imgLocation?

Estou recebendo a imagem de um formulário html.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: imgLocation seria o local físico da imagem ex: C:\minhafoto.jpg, você vai transforma-lá em Stream..

Comment: No meu caso não tem local fisico, não no servidor. A imagem vai vir do navegador do usuário.

Comment: Com esse código você vai ter que salvar a imagem em uma pasta temporária para depois envia-lá

Comment: Não consigo pegar a imagem que o formulário do html recebe e enviar direto para o banco?

Comment: @DiegoGrossi o que está usando ? Asp.NET WebForms, MVC, Core ?

Comment: Rovann estou usando ASP.NET, MVC, Core

Comment: Acho que vc está fazendo uma pequena confusão. Criar blobs (binary large objects) no banco é uma ótima maneira de destruir desempenho, pensando nisso foi criada, alguna anos atrás, essa funcionalidade de "fazer de conta" que vc está salvando um arquivo no banco. Na verdade vc está setando um STREAM, ou seja pegando um array de bytes (o arquivo) mandando pro banco como se fossem dados e este identifica que o tipo da coluna é um arquivo e na pratica salva o arquivo nessa path ai. Isso é muito mais eficiente que salvar no banco mas fica "tranparente" pro desenvolvedor

Answer (score 1):

No seu model, você precisa de uma propriedade do tipo `IFormFile`:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IFormFile Arquivo {get;set;}
}
```

No seu objeto, ou classe POCO, precisa de uma propriedade do tipo `byte[]`:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public byte[] Foto {get;set;}
}
```

E Na action do seu controller, recebe o Model, passa pro `stream` e depois pro `byte[]` e então salva no banco:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(MyModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyObject obj = new MyObject();

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await model.Arquivo.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                obj.Foto = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            await _context.MyObjects.AddAsync(obj);
            _context.SaveChanges();
         }

         return View("Index");
    }
```

> Não se esqueça de, no form, adicionar a propriedade `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu retiro o trecho de código do controller que eu havia informado na pergunta?

Comment: sim, não precisa de mexer com filestream

Answer (score -1):

Tente assim Diego:

// Obtendo URL do arquivo a ser baixado e caminho de destino
// do mesmo

```
string urlArquivo =
    "http://www.minhapagina.com.br/imagens/foto.png";
string caminhoArquivo = 
    @"C:\Temp\Downloads\foto.png";
```

// Outras instruções de código...

// Efetuando o download

```
System.Net.WebClient client =
    new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(urlArquivo, caminhoArquivo);
```

Ai depois você passa o caminhoArquivo

```
FileStream Stream = new FileStream(caminhoArquivo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: Evandro aparentemente a função conseguiu ler a imagem, mas agora estou com problemas de permissão na pasta que criei para receber a imagem no computador. Uso o computador no domínio da empresa com login da empresa e o Visual Studio uso a conta do hotmail que não está no dominio da empresa.

Comment: agora ele está dando outro erro: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Não foi possível localizar o arquivo 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Logo.jpg'.

Comment: você tem que corrigir o caminho, tem que ficar assim @"C:\Temp\Downloads\Logo.jpg! a imagem esta na pasta?

Comment: Esse código está fazendo o download do arquivo, e não o upload

Comment: o caminho que criei foi: C:\imgTemporarias\Logo.jpg. Lá tem essa imagem Logo.jpg, mas ele está gerando esse erro

Comment: Eu preciso que faça o download da imagem que o usuário passar no formulário do HTML

Comment: se o usuário passa uma imagem no formulário html, você deve fazer o upload pro servidor, e não o download

Comment: @Evandro, consegui pegar uma imagem na web e salvar na pasta que criei, agora como faço pra pegar essa imagem na pasta ou o caminho dela e mostrar a imagem na página html?

Comment: `<img src="caminho da imagem" />` mas totalmente fora da pergunta

Comment: Acho que não consegui me expressar bem na pergunta @RovannLinhalis, mas já consegui pegar a imagem também.

Comment: @Evandro, só consigo pegar imagens da web, não consigo passar imagens que estão na minha máquina.